# What is this Spanish dessert?

Tags: dessert, spanish-cuisine

I recently ate one of these in a restaurant in Gran Canaria - they didn't have a menu, you just pointed at things on a trolley. I loved it and asked what the name was but we couldn't quite communicate. I assume it's a Spanish dessert as it was a small, local-ish restaurant, but it might not be.

[image: a delicious mystery dish]

The bottom layer is some sort of dark caramel sauce, then there seems to be perhaps crumbled biscuits, then on top is what I think is Chantilly cream? It's quite a thick cream.

I'd like to try making the dessert myself, but Googling these things together hasn't come up with anything useful.

Thanks!

Comment: So it was sauce on the bottom?  I ask because I would’ve expected it to flow to the bottom of the vessel if that was the case.  The picture looks more like some sort of cake layer on the bottom, like a trifle

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the Canaries have more than just Spanish influence.  Unfortunately, I need to catalog my cookbooks as I couldn’t find my copy of Los Isleños to see if anything similar is mentioned in there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a variation of "Polvito Uruguayo", which is a typical dessert of Grand Canary Island, that is made with cookies, dulce de leche (caramel), and chantilly cream, and which can also be topped with a "suspiros de moya" (a type of sweet meringue).

NOTE: suggested edit of "suspiros de monja" (nuns sighs) is incorrect. The meringue is in fact named after the location "Moya" (a town on Grand Canary Island) which famously produces them.